# Visual Basic Salary tax calculator

Tags: vb.net

The process that I'm trying to create is when a user inputs a number it gets detected by the IF statement to display which tax rate it goes under 20%, 40% or 45%, the amount of tax and the salary after for example If 10,000 inputted the tax rate shows 20% of that which calculates the amount of tax "2000" and the salary after tax "8000".These are the calculations I'm trying to workout, "0 to 31,785 tax rate 20%", but "if less than 10,600 tax rate 0%", 31,786 to 150,000 tax rate 40% if less than 42,385 tax rate 0%", over15,000 tax rate 45%.

I have managed to do that for one some IF statement but when I try to do that for the next IF statement the numbers get mixed up and display the wrong results or don't display the tax rate that suppose to show.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCalc.Click
        Dim decSalary, decTax, decTax2, decTax3, decAmount As Decimal

        decSalary = textSalary.Text
        decTax = decSalary * 0.2
        decTax2 = decSalary * 0.4
        decTax3 = decSalary * 0.45
        decAmount = decSalary - decTax


        lblTax.Text = FormatPercent(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.45, TriState.UseDefault)
        Return
        lblAmount.Text = Format(decTax, "currency")
        lblFinal.Text = Format(decAmount, "currency")

        If (decSalary <= 10500) Then
            decTax *= 0
        ElseIf (decSalary >= 10600) Then
            decTax *= 0.2
        ElseIf (decSalary <= 31785) Then
            decTax *= 0.2

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textSalary.TextChanged
        'Dim decSalary, decTax, decTax2, decAmount As Decimal

        ' lblTax.Text = FormatPercent(0.0)
        ' lblAmount.Text = Format(decTax, "currency")
        ' lblFinal.Text = Format(decAmount, "currency")

        ' If decSalary <= 10500 Then
        'decTax = 0
        ' ElseIf decSalary >= 10600 Then
        ' decTax = 0.2
        '  ElseIf decSalary <= 31785 Then
        '  decTax2 = decTax

        '  End If




    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdClear.Click
        textSalary.Clear()
        lblTax.Text = "0%"
        lblAmount.Text = "0"
        lblFinal.Text = "0"

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: why is this tagged `c++`?

Comment: Even though I do my own taxes (in the USA), I don't understand your question. "31,786 to 150,000 tax rate 40% if less than 42,385 tax rate 0%". The person would still be taxed if they made < 42,385 so what is that phrase supposed to mean?

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples of what you mean by "... when I try to do that for the next IF statement the numbers get mixed up ..." and what exactly the first and second IF statements are?

Comment: The work that I'm suppose to produce is asking for that type of calculation here is the table tax I'm using to produce the work: "basic rate 20% from 0 to 31,785, people with the standard PA start paying this rate on income over 10,600", the next tax is, " higher rate 40% from 31,786 to 150,000, people with the standard PA start paying this rate on income over 42,385 the next tax rate is 45% from 150,000 +, so from these I need to produce the salary, tax rate, amount of tax and salary after tax. topshot

Comment: As you can see from my code I tried to calculate with the IF statement "If (decSalary <= 10500) Then
            decTax *= 0 " but when I try to use the ElseIF it wont show the tax or the amount - Taegost

Comment: "If 10,000 inputted the tax rate shows 20% of that which calculates the amount of tax "2000" and the salary after tax "8000" " - Tax doesn't work like that. You're only taxed on the amount above the allowance, so that up to £10,000 you pay none, but £12000 you pay none on the first £10,000 then 20% * on the remaining £2000 only* - and so on regarding the other bands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `If` and `ElseIf` statements are failing to execute as you are expecting them as the conditional order and operators used do not make sense.

```
If (decSalary <= 10500) Then  ' For all integers less than/equal to 10500
    decTax *= 0
ElseIf (decSalary >= 10600) Then  ' For all integers more than/equal to 10600
    decTax *= 0.2
ElseIf (decSalary <= 31785) Then  ' For all integers less than/equal to 31785
    decTax *= 0.2
End If
```

Once one of the `If` statements has been evaluated, execution will jump into the block and will exit at the `End If`; the other If statements will not be evaluated. For any number of decSalary over 10600, decTax will always the result of itself be multiplied by 0.2.  Additionally the third conditional will never be hit unless decSalary is between 10501-10599, and even then the result will still be the same as if the value was over 10600.

You are setting the values of the labels before calculating the tax amount. You are declaring variables for all of the different tax amounts, however you are only using one of them in your code.

One last thing, it appears as though you are using `TextBox` for all of your input controls. There are specific controls for handling numeric input and I would suggest implementing them.

Here's is an incomplete example of how to perform the logic and output that you are asking for defined as you have it written in your question:

```
Private Sub CalculateDisplayAmounts(ByVal salary As Decimal)
    Dim taxRate As Decimal = GetTaxRate(salary)
    Dim taxAmount As Decimal = salary * taxRate
    Dim takeHomePay As Decimal = salary - taxAmount

    taxRateLabel.Invoke(Sub(x) taxRateLabel.Text = FormatPercent(x), taxRate)
    taxAmountLabel.Invoke(Sub(x) taxAmountLabel.Text = FormatCurrency(x), taxAmount)
    takeHomeLabel.Invoke(Sub(x) takeHomeLabel.Text = FormatCurrency(x), takeHomePay)
End Sub

Private Function GetTaxRate(ByVal salaryAmount As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim taxRate As Decimal = 0D
    If salaryAmount <= 31785D Then
        If salaryAmount >= 10600D Then
            taxRate = 0.2D
        End If
    ElseIf salaryAmount <= 150000 Then
        If salaryAmount >= 42385D Then
            taxRate = 0.4D
        End If
    Else
        taxRate = 0.45D
    End If

    Return taxRate
End Function
```